# How to save current dashboard selections in Powerapps

Tags: save, powerapps

I have created a standalone app in Powerapps. It is basically just a dashboard with a text input box, a number of toggle switches and radio buttons.

The dashboard will be used just to confirm a list of actions have been started or completed.
There is no requirement to save the data as such, but I need the option to keep the toggle selections and radio buttons etc as they were previously when a user opens the app.

At present the app works great however when closed and reopened the options revert to their default selections.

I have a button that resets the selections if required but I need them to remain unchanged unless reset manually.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to persist the data *somewhere*, whether that is in locally on the device (more difficult, does not work for apps in-browser; mobile only) or in a data table somewhere (easy).

[On-device example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-savedata-loaddata#simple-offline-example)

**Data table (Sharepoint) example:**

- When user clicks "Save", `Patch()` the data to a Sharepoint list
- `OnStart` of the app, set a variable for the logged in user, then lookup in the Sharepoint list, all settings for varUser.
- `ClearCollect` these into a local collection.
- Use `UpdateIf` on each field to update the Collection
- When user clicks "Save", `Patch()` the Sharepoint list, repeat.

Comment: So I've managed to create the patch formula and now have the data stored in a SharePoint list. I am still having trouble finding a way to load the toggle positions to the app when it's reopened. There are two records in the list and they have around 30 columns each column represents a toggle button, one row represents a seperate page. Why is it so complicated to perform a task that should be native.

Comment: "`OnStart` of the app, set a variable for the logged in user (`Set(varUser, User().Email)`, then lookup in the Sharepoint list, all settings for varUser." (`ClearCollect(colUserData, Filter(SHAREPOINTLIST, userColumn = varUser))`)